# MYSQL delete specific row button PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am building a very basic forum with the ability to comment on posts. As you can see, this code shows the commments and when the comment author is equal to the logged in user, it should show a delete button to delete the comment. The problem is now that when I click the delete button, it deletes all the comments on the post and not only the comment with the delete button next to it.

My 'comments' table has the columns id, discid, comment_username, comment and comment_time in which the discid column from 'comments' refers to the id column in the table 'dicussions'

```
    <?php

    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM discussions WHERE `id` = '.$id.' LIMIT 1';
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    ?>
            <h2><? echo $row['category'] . $row['topic']; ?></h2>
            <div>Posted on <? echo $row['date_time']; ?> by <? echo $row['username'] ?></div>
            <div><? echo $row['discussion']; ?></div>

     <?

$result_comments = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE discid = $id ORDER BY comment_time ASC");

        while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($result_comments))

        {

        ?>
                <form action="" method="POST" >
                  <? echo $record['comment_username']. $record['comment_time'] ?>   

                  <!-- if comment from logged in user, show delete option -->
                  <? 
                  if ($record['comment_username'] == $log_username) 
                    { 
                      echo '<span><button title="Delete comment" value="' . $record['id'] .'" name="deletecommentbutton" type="submit">X</button></span>';
                    } 
                    if(isset($_POST['deletecommentbutton']))
                    { 
                      $commentid = $record['id'];
                      $result_delete = mysql_query("DELETE from comments WHERE id='$commentid'");
                      header("Location: url/discussion_view.php?id=".$_GET['id']."");
                    }
                  ?>

                <div><? echo $record['comment'] ?></div></form>

          <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all you should not use `mysql_*` functions anymore. It's deprecated.

Instead you can use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo).

And about your problem, statement `if(isset($_POST['deletecommentbutton']))` is `true` for every comment on given post because you are not checking ID of selected comment.
You should move deletion code outside of loop and execute it only for selected ID.

Comment: How can I execute it only for selected ID?

Comment: Just use value from `$_POST['deletecommentbutton']` which is ID of selected comment.  But don't forget to sanitize it!

Comment: Could you give me an example or a way to get started? I can't get it to work :(

Comment: Sorry but I can't write code for you. You've got ID in `$_POST` array and you have to use it in your query. That's one of the basic tasks in every `PHP` + `MySQL` tutorials.